# Trying to use union to index data in struct

Tags: c, indexing, struct, segmentation-fault, unions

I'm trying to retrieve data from a file in which it is stored with the format a:b:c:d:e:f, and I want to use a `union` to index each field in the `struct`. Namely, I should define the `union` and the `struct` as below, but I run into a bunch of warnings when I try to use the union/struct, and, of course, segmentation fault error.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FIELDS 6

typedef union{
  char a[FIELDS];
  struct {
    char* a;
    char* b;
    char* c;
    char* d;
    char* e;
    char* f;
  } s;
} Elements;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s data\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  const int COLONS = 5;
  const int MAXFIELDS = 5000;

  char *buffer = 0;
  char *token = 0;
  size_t len = 0;
  size_t field_length = 0;
  ssize_t nread;
  Elements* totalElements = malloc(MAXFIELDS);
  int total_elements = 0;

  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while ((nread = getline(&buffer, &len, fp)) != 1) {
    token = strtok(buffer, ":");

    field_length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%s", token );
    totalElements[total_elements].a[0] = malloc( field_length );
    strcpy (totalElements[total_elements].a[0], token);

    for (int i = 1; i < COLONS - 1; i++){

      field_length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%s", token );
      totalElements[total_elements].a[i] = malloc( field_length );
      strcpy (totalElements[total_elements].a[i], token);

      token = strtok(NULL, ":");

    }

    field_length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%s", token );
    totalElements[total_elements].a[COLONS - 1] = malloc( field_length );
    strcpy (totalElements[total_elements].a[COLONS - 1], token);

    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");

    field_length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%s", token );
    totalElements[total_elements].a[COLONS] = malloc( field_length );
    strcpy (totalElements[total_elements].a[COLONS], token);

    total_elements++;
  }

  fclose (fp);
  free (buffer);
  free (totalElements);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

  return 0;
}
```

The warnings the compiler gcc shows:

```
ex.c:51:40: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     totalElements[total_elements].a[0] = malloc( field_length );
                                        ^ ex.c:52:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     strcpy (totalElements[total_elements].a[0], token);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from ex.c:6:0: /usr/include/string.h:121:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’  extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict
__dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^~~~~~ ex.c:57:42: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       totalElements[total_elements].a[i] = malloc( field_length );
                                          ^ ex.c:58:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       strcpy (totalElements[total_elements].a[i], token);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from ex.c:6:0: /usr/include/string.h:121:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’  extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict
__dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^~~~~~ ex.c:65:49: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     totalElements[total_elements].a[COLONS - 1] = malloc( field_length );
                                                 ^ ex.c:66:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     strcpy (totalElements[total_elements].a[COLONS - 1], token);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from ex.c:6:0: /usr/include/string.h:121:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’  extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict
__dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^~~~~~ ex.c:71:45: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     totalElements[total_elements].a[COLONS] = malloc( field_length );
                                             ^ ex.c:72:13: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     strcpy (totalElements[total_elements].a[COLONS], token);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from ex.c:6:0: /usr/include/string.h:121:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’  extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict
__dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^~~~~~
```

Comment: Is there some special reason why you don't show the warnings?

Comment: `strcpy (totalElements[total_elements].a[0], token);` With `a` being of type `char a[6]` `a[0]` is of type `char` (not some char array) which is not a valid parameter for `strcpy.`

Comment: @Gerhardh Oh sorry, I will add them immediately

Comment: @4386427 Yes, the memory allocation of totalElements is wrong. But that still doesn't fix the program. I'm trying to understand what am I doing wrong and how to index a struct successfully

Comment: All your warnings are caused by mismatch of char <-> pointer types.

Comment: What do you mean by " I want to use a  union to index each field in the struct." ? The problem with your code (i.e. all the warning) is that you keep using a **char** as if it is a **char pointer** In other word `a[i]` is a char - not a char pointer. If you want to access the char pointer `a` you need `totalElements[total_elements].s.a` but I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I believe `char a[FIELDS]` should be actually `char * a[FIELDS]`.

Comment: I think you should write it like this `Elements* totalElements = malloc(Elements *)` to make the system allocate the appropriate value.

Comment: @montonero Yes, exactly. That's it. Thank you. If you explain that in an answer I'll select that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `char a[FIELDS]` field in the union should be `char * a[FIELDS]` since the struct is of `char *` and `char a[]` is not an array of `char *` but array of `char`.